# How to install library LIBSVM for python to be used for Anaconda3 on MacOS 10.14

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, libsvm

I have installed libsvm on my mac (using make) and it is working fine when I execute python commands using terminal. But I couldn't import the library in Anaconda3.

For Anaconda3 I have tried the following commands in python console:

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 libsvm`

libsvm installs but couldn't be imported

and

`pip install libsvm`

Error is encountered with some missing header files
(Maybe the cause of the problem)

What is the way out?

P.S: While 'making' through terminal I had to change the standard c++ libraries

Comment: How did you try to import it in Python? Where have you seen an example of LIBSVM being used in Python? While [the LIBSVM package has some Python scripts](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/tree/master/python), it doesn't have a true package, and the Conda installer won't even include them.  Perhaps the closest thing to a package are [the bindings provided by Bob](https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/stable/bob/bob.learn.libsvm/doc/index.html).

Comment: I simply used 'make' in the libsvm-3.24/python directory. Through this I was able to do `import svmutil`. Sorry, but I am not able to use bob. Could you tell how to import it? Thanks

Comment: then it sounds like it works: those scripts are all there are, i.e., import `svm` or `svmutil` or `commonutil`